# Instantiating a generic class within a method body of that class

Tags: java, list, generics

I'm trying to instantiate a generic class within a method of that class, but am having compile-time errors. Hopefully someone can provide some insight here:

```
//returns a new ILo<T> with all items in this list that satisfy
//the given predicate
public ILo<T> filter(ISelect<T> pred);


// Represents a nonempty list of items of type T
class ConsLo<T> implements ILo<T>{
    T first;
    ILo<T> rest;


//returns a new ILo<T> with all items in this list that satisfy
//the given predicat
public ILo<T> filter(ISelect pred) {
    return new ConsLo<T>(pred.select(this.first),
             this.rest.filter(pred));
}
```

I've provided the interface definition of method, followed by the definition of the ConsLo class, followed by the method declaration that I'm dealing with. I don't understand how I can instantiate this class while keeping things generic so as to work with any type and predicate pred. Here's the compiler error:

```
ILo.java:95: error: method select in interface ISelect<T#3> cannot be applied to given types;
return new ConsLo<T>(pred.select(this.first),
                         ^
required: T#1
found: T#2
reason: actual argument T#2 cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>filter(ISelect<T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in class ConsLo
T#3 extends Object declared in interface ISelect
```

Comment: Your implementation of `filter` doesn't require a generic `ISelect`, that may be your problem.

Comment: Probably should be `public ILo<T> filter(ISelect<T> pred) {` note the **<T>** added.

Comment: I tried both ideas and neither compiled

Comment: @BlakeMadden What is the interface for `ISelect`?

Comment: Damn it, the ISelect method select returns a type boolean if the given element fits the predicate criteria. I changed the method body to an if statement checking that boolean value and then returning a new ConsLo<T>(this.first, this.rest.filter(pred)); instead. Sorry for wasting everyone's time, thanks for the info about ISelect<T>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the generic version of `ISelect`:

```
public ILo<T> filter(ISelect<T> pred) {
    return new ConsLo<T>(pred.select(this.first),
        this.rest.filter(pred));
}
```

This way `pred` will be `ISelect<T>`, not ISelect - that are the two types `T#1` and `T#2` the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Note of pedantry: In Java it's called Generics.

Comment: I usually use that, but many people started to call it *template* - I suppose that's the way the beginners understand it more easily, that's why I used it here. Otherwise you're right, I'm making an update.

Comment: Yes, this was a needed change, but I had an underlying problem with the method select that I was calling being of type boolean instead of type T. Thanks for your input, I'll accept it when I can

Comment: @GaborSch - well "they" are wrong.  C++ has templates, and Java has generics.  C++ templates behave in a "template like" fashion; i.e. they produce in lots of different classes when you instantiate them. Java's generics don't behave that way at all.  The difference is more than plain pedantry.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm not familiar with C++, only with Java, and I know how Java works since 1.3. I only mentioned that at the starter level they look similar (although the behaviour is different). Maybe time to educate :) I'll care for that in the future.